# Android wear compatibility with Samsung Tizen

Tags: wear-os, tizen

Can Android wear library be used with Samsung Tizen watch ? How would i get a emulator for Samsung Tizen if so ? So to be more clear i want to create a android app(using android sdk) but have it send messages to samsung Tizen watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no compatibility between the two; two completely different OS/Frameworks.